# web page controls binds with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to design mobile application and have included jquery mobile 1.4.0.css and js file also, I am using slide transition while navigating through pages and code is as,

```
$.mobile.changePage( "../resources/confirm.html", {
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: false
});
```

i am binding/ applying css on pageload event of jquery but when page loads, page loads completely and a half second later css gets applied whichever i have written in pageload (means when slide transition completes). I tried `pageshow`, `pagebeforeshow` but no luck.

```
$(document).on({
    "pageinit" : function() { },
    "pageshow" : function() {     
        if (capacity) {
            if (unitpreferance === 1) {
                $("#number-pattern").val(capacity);
                capacityMet = Math.round(parseFloat(capacity * 3.5169));
                document.getElementById("lblCapaUnit").innerHTML = 'Tons';
            }
            else {
                $("#number-pattern").val(capacityMet);
                document.getElementById("lblCapaUnit").innerHTML = 'kW';
           }
        }
    }
}, "#MyPage");
```

Please help

Comment: `pagebeforeshow` or `pagecontainerbeforeshow` should work for you. `#MyPage` is the page being loaded?

Comment: @Omar, #MyPage is id of div of that page, on which these operations are to be performed.